# In what situations are Django formsets used?

Tags: django

I am a beginner with Django. In what situations are Django formsets used? (In real applications.)

Please give some examples.

Comment: Best described here ..https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/formsets/

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/)

> A formset is a layer of abstraction to working with multiple forms on the same page. It can be best compared to a data grid.

So any time you want to have multiple instances of a particular form displayed on a page for creation or updating. An example of this might be a Phonebook. Each Form is a single entry in the phonebook, but a Formset of Phonbook forms will allow you to create or edit multiple entries in one go.

Answer (score 0):

One case is when ModelA have a foreign key to ModelB. you can say that one ModelB has many ModelA, so lets say that ModelB is a Invoice and ModelA is the ProductItem, one invoice has one or many product items.

In the practice now you can make a basic formset like that: http://help.mailchimp.com/img/addafieldoption.jpg where you can add more product items to a invoice.